# Get blog.domain.com to appear as www.domain.com/blog

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, blogs, subdomain

I want to create a blog for an e-commerce website, but due to data security reasons I don't want to host the blog on the same machine as the website is hosted on.  Is there a way to 
host it on a separate machine using the sub-domain of blog.domain.com but have it be accessible via the url www.domain.com/blog.

My reasoning is that the content will help with seo better if it uses the same domain.

I was thinking about using mod_rewrite but I'm not sure if it would allow page retrieval from a different website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the Apache module mod_proxy to make the contents of a server appear to be hosted on another server, and therefore appear to be hosted under a different domain. You might like to take a read of [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) which details the Apache configuration directives needed to get it up and running. If that doesn't offer enough options for setting it up how you want it, then you could investigate the "force proxy" option in mod_rewrite, which allows you to send certain rewritten requests through mod_proxy to do the proxying.

Comment: Thanks, got me started in the right direction, looks like I'm going to have to recompile apache for freebsd to get this module working.